# How to prevent users of particular role to access the content view (node view) of a particular content type?

Tags: 7, users

I am using [Content Access Module](https://drupal.org/project/content_access) and have rebuild permissions after enabling the module.

After giving restricted access to users having role 'Data Entry Operator'.
I have a content type delivery challan for which I have **ticked** on the following permissions for the role ABC.

**View own delivery_challan content**(selected the particular permission for role 'Data Entry Operator' only ) and 
**View any delivery_challan content**(unselected the particular permission for role 'Data Entry Operator')

Here is the screenshot of the permissions set in the content access module.
[image]

When I login as user having role Data Entry Operator , I should not be able to view the contents of type 'delivery challan'
But the issue is I am able to view the content
How can I prevent user from viewing this content??

Comment: You can able to view the content if you created the content.. As per settings you mentioned you can see own content that means content created by you.. But content is created by some one else then you should get access denied..

Comment: Yes but I am able to see others content as well. But according to view that should not be the case

Answer (score 0):

Ok  there was a mistake from my side 

the view 'any delivery_challan content' permission was given to
authenticated user.
And by default any user has role authenticated user.
So User having role 'Data Admin Operator' was able to view any delivery challan content as user also has the role 'authenticated user'
**So the solution is to remove the authenticated role from the list of roles under the view any delivery challan content**